# Simple audio mixer with "remote" control

Tags: audio

I am looking for a audio mixer with at least 3 inputs that has a form of remote control, such as rs232 or some other interface.

This needs to be able to control the 3 sources volume interdependently, like the ones suggested on here [Two Audio Sources -> One set of speakers](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7201/two-audio-sources-one-set-of-speakers/9559#9559) but with control over a digital interface.

Comment: Is this for (semi) pro work or home use?

Comment: Home, audio quality is important but control is a bigger factor

Comment: What's your budget?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a few digital audio mixers used at live events, and while they are impressive, they can be somewhat expensive.

[Here](https://www.sweetwater.com/c1061--iPad_iPhone_Live_Sound_Mixers) are a few examples...

Comment: If you can afford it, I've used a Behringer x32 and love it.  In @Hitek's link to Sweetwater (a great online store for audio equipment BTW.  Ordered from them several times.) I see there's an x32 compact.  That would be a great choice!